# Chrome sometimes get element as node sometimes as markup

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

**Chrome browser sometimes get and logs element like below**

[image]

**And sometimes like below**

[image]

Code I am using a very simple javascript code.

```
const $dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.has-dropdown');
  console.log($dropdowns[0]);
  var drp = $dropdowns[0].querySelector('.navbar-dropdown');
  console.log(drp);
```

Why I see this difference?

When I refresh the page chrome sometimes shows first style (I guess node style) and sometimes only markup.

If is there a way to choose how to show them I prefer to show it always in first style.

I've tried in other browsers I don't see it. It happens only in chrome.

Comment: that's really odd ... use firefox instead

Comment: Do you think this is something to do with PHP?  (if not, please remove the tag).